# c# datatable using compute to calculate an average on a range of rows

Tags: c#, datatable, average

I am trying to use .Compute on a datatable whereby it only calculates an average on a set of rows. I have looked through the Microsoft docs and searched for a while and cannot find where a filter works against the datatable structure. Looking for something like: -

```
string connectStatement = "SELECT Price FROM PData WHERE Code = '" + this.ItemCode + "' ORDER BY TradeDate DESC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 300 ROWS ONLY";
DataTable itemsDT = ConnectionManager.GetTable(connectStatement);
Records20 = (decimal)itemsDT.Compute("Avg(Price)", "Rows > 16 AND Rows < 23");
```

It works when using an empty filter but calculates on all of the data.

If this is not possible, I am considering using a loop and sum to calculate the average after.

**EDIT:** I am looking at sample of data at a point in time and averaging a range either side of this (e.g. being the 20th interval and rows 17 - 22)

The error message is
$exception  {"Cannot find column [Rows]."} - System.Data.EvaluateException

Sample data (limited to first 30 rows):

Price
6464.100,
6426.800,
6406.100,
6349.300,
6329.600,
6295.500,
6247.900,
6189.100,
6206.100,
6214.600,
6231.000,
6130.200,
6115.700,
6129.500,
6097.300,
6159.600,
6149.700,
6118.400,
6156.700,
6118.800,
6054.700,
6014.700,
6198.000,
6242.800,
6272.900,
6250.700,
6213.500,
6207.000,
6184.200,
6333.200

Comment: What error message are you getting? What is your data structure and can you please add some sample data.

Comment: Hi Peter. I have just updated the information as requested. As mentioned above, if this cannot be filtered within the .Compute function, I will use a loop and calculate average from there. Thank you for your interest...

Comment: It's interpreting `Rows` as a field name; a query specifying row count will not work. I'm not familiar with `Compute` but I don;t think you can use it in that way.

Comment: Simple with a WHERE : itemsDT.AsEnumerable().Where((x,index) => (index > 16) && (index < 23))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to do this the way you're approaching it.

To use the `.Compute` method, you need to pass a column name in the filter expression - as it is a normal `WHERE` clause. At a T-SQL level you can utilize the `ROW_NUMBER` function to enumerate the returned rows in a new column - say *Index* - then apply the filter on that enumerated column. E.g.,

```
string connectStatement = "SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY TradeDate DESC) AS Index, Price FROM PData WHERE Code = '" + this.ItemCode + "' OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 300 ROWS ONLY";
DataTable itemsDT = ConnectionManager.GetTable(connectStatement);
Records20 = (decimal)itemsDT.Compute("Avg(Price)", "Index > 16 AND Index < 23");
```

Another approach would be to do this with the aid of `LINQ` and leave the T-SQL query as is:

```
string connect statement = "SELECT Price FROM PData WHERE Code = '" + this.ItemCode + "' ORDER BY TradeDate DESC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 300 ROWS ONLY";
Records20 = itemsDT.AsEnumerable() // this will yeald a IEnumerable<DataRow>
    .Skip(16)
    .Take(7)
    .Select(dr => (decimal)dr["Price"])
    .Average()
;
```

Comment: Hi Bozhidar. Thank you for your answer. I did find the first suggestion else where but as I am looking at several points of data in time, I thought this wouldn't be efficient therefore load the 300 records into a dataTable.
Thank you for the second solution.

Comment: FYI, `ROW_NUMBER` don't add overhead to your existing query. The DB engine is smart enough to optimize the enumeration to only the needed records. I think that the ordering is the key performance concern here which is done anyway, even without the `ROW_NUMBER`. So don't worry and at least give it a try. Further, if you can afford it, do filter in the T-SQL query. That way filtering is done at the DB server and only the useful data traversing the wire. The `LINQ` solution works with the data that was already loaded in the RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution using a loop

```
decimal sumCalculation = 0;
for (int record = 17; record < 23; record++)
{
     sumCalculation += decimal.Parse(itemsDT.Rows[record]["Price"].ToString());
}
Records20 = sumCalculation / 6;
```